# How to re-slick with expandable slides

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

I have created a slick slider that contains expandable slides. A slide contains and image and a div with some text in it.

The div has a width of 0, and when clicking on the image the div expands. The slider fits 9 slides before arrows/dots are needed, i.e. `slidesToShow` is set to 9.

If I do not  However, when the slide expands, the slides at the end are no longer visible and arrows are required.

I tried playing with a few different settings but nothing seems to work. I thought `setPosition` might do it, but no luck.

What is the best way to detect when the slides are no longer fully visible within the slider, and how would I get the arrows to appear in this situation and disappear when the slides are collapsed (i.e. they are all visible within the slider)?